# How to wipe Eclipse back to a fresh install state?

Tags: eclipse

I've inherited an Eclipse installation that is packed with extensions and marketplace packages, and I would like to reset it back to a clean install state.  However, I would also want to avoid having to reinstall Eclipse.  Does anyone know if it's possible to reset Eclipse back to a fresh install state without having to uninstall it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In ***Help > About Eclipse IDE*** click the button ***Installation Details***
2. In the ***Installation History* tab** select a date and click ***Revert***